# Thread Pool for Multi-Threaded Webserver

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, queue, threadpool

I want to write a multi-threaded web-server and I should use a thread pool. Can I use a queue for thread pool and if so, do you suggest that the queue be circular or say double-linked list? Which one will be better for my web-server implementation? If queue is not a good choice, what data structure is recommended for the thread pool?

Comment: A stack ( single linked list ) should be fine. All you need to do is pop one off when you need it and push it back on when you are done with it. No need for a queue or circular or doubly linked list.

Comment: A circular queue may also do the trick, see this nice, lightweight library: [threadpool](https://github.com/mbrossard/threadpool).

Comment: You may utilize [**application server**](http://appserver.io)  recently developed in PHP which in turn uses C language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any queue that is thread safe. 
But if that web server is going to be under heavy duty, it might be better to use lock free queues based on arrays, so that you only have to allocate the array sometimes, (michael and scott's queue is based on nodes, and so in naive implementations you have to allocate nodes every time you make an enqueue, and free them on the dequeue).
(So to answer, array based queues (and not deques) in my opinion are better since they are fair among the different tasks.)

I suggest you use a queue, not a deque. (Eventhough work stealing uses a deque, you want to be fair attending clients. And so a deque, since ot behaves like a stack, the first request would be the last answered.)
You can see this page for lock free concurrent queues (this is the state of the art i think)
http://mcg.cs.tau.ac.il/projects/lcrq/